# Stepping Number program

Tags: algorithm

I have the following problem:

> **The stepping number:**
>
> A number is called a stepping number if every adjacent digits, separated by commas, differ by 1. A stepping number can't be a 1-digit number, it must be at least a 2-digit number. For example, **45** and ***8,343,545*** are stepping numbers.
>   But, ***890,098*** is not. The difference between ‘9’ and ‘0’ should
>   not be considered as 1.
>
> Given start number ***s*** and an end number ***e*** your function should list
>   out all the stepping numbers in the range including both the numbers ***s***
>   & ***e***.

**My Attempt**:

```
public void steppingNumber(int s, int e) {
    while(s <= e) {
        String str = Integer.parseInt(s);
        if(isSteppingNumber(str)) System.out.print(str + " ");
        s++;
    }
}

public boolean isSteppingNumber(String str) {
    if(str.length() == 1) return false; // 1-digit number can't be a stepping number

    List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    while(str.length() >= 3) { // get every 3-digit comma-separated number
        numbers.add(str.substring(str.length()-3));
        str = str.substring(0,str.length()-3);
    }
    numbers.add(str); // Also get the last number left

    for(String num : numbers) { // for every 3-digit comma-separated number, check if it's a stepping number
        for(int i = 1; i < num.length(); i++) {
            int previousDigit = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i-1));
            int currentDigit = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i));

            if(Math.abs(previousDigit - currentDigit) != 1) return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

If the question were only to check if a number was a stepping number, I think my solution would be fine. However, if I should list all stepping numbers within the range, say 1 to 10^15, then my solution will run linear time, leave alone the checking part. Can anyone give a better solution for the given problem?

Comment: This is better for codereview.stackexchange.com where optimization problems belong.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that

Comment: Sure, this maybe better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com but OP is new to the site and yet has used code tags and shown some effort

Comment: here's an idea.. each set of 2-3 digits have nothing to do with each other. a lookup table from 0-999 for isSteppingNumber will speed up the code if you can rethink the logic a little

Comment: That's right, surely it'll speed up the checking part. But, the problem is I have to print out all the stepping numbers in a given range. In my solution, I iterated from number s to e, which had linear time complexity. I wonder if somehow I could get around the linear time from checking every number between s and e inclusive because the difference between s and e could be very big. Thanks for your suggestion though

Comment: This question was cross-posted on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/74441/9357), which is a more appropriate place for it.

Comment: Yes. I moved my question there because somebody, earlier, suggested so. Thank you for bringing that up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking every number in **[s,e]**, you can try printing every stepping number in **[s,e]**.

It should looks like:

1. Generate a list of 3-digit stepping number with value in [000,999]
2. Create another list (for leftmost part before the comma) by add 1 to 9 into the new list and then add all element in list 1
3. Find the smallest stepping number greater than or equal to s and check if the stepping number is in **[s,e]**
4. Generate stepping numbers (by using list 1 and list 2) until the value is greater than e

---

**Remark**

List 1 holds 010 and 012, but exclude value start with `0` but not `01` like 045 (even 45 itself is a valid value)

s and/or e smaller than or equal to 2-digit value might need to handle specially.